# Conditional on price

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

Hi wondering if it's possible to do a conditional on price inside of the product tags.

For example..

```
{if price > '0.00'} Hello {/if}
```

I'd like display different formatting if price is more than 0.00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably want to use `price_val` in your conditionals since it will output just the value minus any currency formatting.

```
{if price_val > 0}Hello{/if}
```

If you have a product with a price of £10.00 price_val would output 10.00

You can add `_val` to any of the price related tags like `{sale_price_val}` or `{price_inc_mod_val}`

From the docs:

> All price variables are pre-formatted according to your currency formatting settings. If you want the unformatted amount, simply append _val to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is working:

```
{if price != "£0.00"} Hello {/if}
```